# Two .htaccess files. One in root and one in wordpress in a sub-directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having an issue with .htaccess files (something that I do not really understand) - therefore, if I could get an explanation along with an answer that would be incredible!

Anyway, the situation is as follows.

Aim : I am trying to remove the www portion of my website so that it loads up always as XXX.com.

I have a root directory with an .htaccess coded as follows :

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

This works well for it's purpose. However, in a directory called "Info" I have an installation of Wordpress with it's own .htaccess which currently looks like :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /info/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /info/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This does not remove the www and is the standard WordPress installation .htaccess file. My question is, what do I have to do to this file or the root directory file to fix the canonical issue!

Thanks a bunch,

Alex

Comment: the scheme part of the URL tells to the browser which protocol to use for the request. So you can not remove it, unless it is a relative path.

Comment: I disagree because at the moment I am in the situation where the pages in the root directory load as domain.com. If I move to the WP directory it loads as http://www.trumanassociates.co.uk/info/ (with THE HTTP:// at the beginning)

Comment: missed `RewriteEngine On` in the first set. `http://` part hides the browser itself.

Comment: The first .htaccess works fine though?! So if you go to this URL : http://trumanassociates.co.uk you will see no HTTP. If you go  http://trumanassociates.co.uk/info you will see the HTTP? Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean `www`? There is no redirect on `www.` in the second set. May be it makes the WordPress script.

Comment: Yep, I mean www... Wow, my excuse is that in my timezone it's pretty late! So yes, let me clarify here (and will clarify in the main question) I am trying to remove the www as per on the homepage!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself. In WP it was surprisingly easy to do.

I logged into wp-login.php and then proceeded through to General settings where I removed the "www." from both listed URLs... Worked a charm!

Comment: I am sorry, but this is not a solution. Changing from www. to without www. is a big change for many websites.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules that are in htaccess files have precedence in subfolders first. Meaning the htaccess file in the `/info/` folder completely supercedes any rules in parent directories. That's why the rule in your root directory is being ignored.

If you're using apache 2.4, you can use the [InheritBefore](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) option:

```
RewriteOption InheritBefore
```

which makes any rules in the parent directory get applied before any rules in the current directory.

If you're not using apache 2.4, then you'll have to duplicate the rules **before** the wordpress rules:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule> 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /info/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /info/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, however it hasn't worked. The InherhitBefore option produced a 500 error ( I assume therefore that I am not using Apache 2.4 ). The second option once implemented stops the page from ever rendering.